# JAVA Objectreference

Tags: java

If I have a class A and build one instance with "new" of it. But add this instance to 2 ArrayLists, is the instance of A 2 times in memory?

Pseudo code:

```
class A() {String s;}
A a = new A();
List<A> list1 = new ArrayList<A>();
List<A> list2 = new ArrayList<A>();
list1.Add(a);
list2.Add(a);
```

Freudi

Comment: object references will be added in your list objects. Hence no memory allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. You only store the object reference.

In your code snippet, you create three references: `a`, the one stored into `list1` and the one stored into `list2`. All of these three reference the same object, so if you modify either (via mutation methods of class `A`), modifications will be reflected to all three.

Comment: the three references are not the same. They reference the same object.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's still just one instance of A, two instances of List and two references to the instance of A, a.